# Email delivery failure notification: "Domain of sender address..... does not exist. Giving up on (IP address)"

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

We received the following mail delivery error when someone from our organization attempted to email a (valid) Gmail email account:

> *"Domain of sender address..... does not exist. Giving up on (IP address)"*

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Means they used spoofing to prevent the actual ip Adress for being recorded.

Comment: I guess the domain that was shown at the dots does indeed not exist?

Comment: It exists all right. It looks like emails to other domains are not making it through at the moment (just started happening 24 hours ago). No problem receiving inbound emails. I'm still waiting to hear back from the provider to see if our mail server has been blacklisted or something- but no response yet. At least two of our accounts are having this problem, and I know that one of them never sends any emails. My feeling is that it's not just a matter of one account being blacklisted- this probably affects all email accounts on our domain. Never seen the error before so not sure what's going on.